# What is the dosage of UV-C radiation received when water flows past a UV purification tube of a given length at a given flow rate

Tags: radiation

A UV-C lamp is typically a tube with a nominal diameter of 5/8" or 1", and a length between around 12cm and about 90cm.

For a water purification application, the water enters in at one end of a stainless steel (?) cylinder, which has a UV tube in the middle

[image]

and then goes out the other end, having passed over the length of the tube.

It should be obvious that the tube is not a point source, so for example a certain 55W tube, which is 895mm long  claims 18.0W in the 200-280nm wavelength range, but that 18W is the total amount of radiation across the length of the tube, whereas for example when the water enters the purifier the radiation dose from the far end of the tube will be much less.

If our filter is made of stainless steel, then there will be relatively poor reflection of UV-C (because stainless steel is a poor reflector of UV-C). For the sake of argument let us assume that the reflection is zero, and that the water itself has no impurities so that there is zero absorption of the radiation dose.

Treating the entire 200-280nm range as equivalent (which it's not, but let's treat it as such for the purposes of this), I see that it is normal to quote a radiation dose in mJ/cm^2, which varies depending on the target organism (E coli or whatever), but an international standard for water treatment is 40 mJ/cm^2.

Obviously we have a fluid, namely water,  and typically we would quote '10 litres per second' as the flow rate, rather than anything involving an area.

Therefore, given these parameters:

- UV tube length 895mm
- UV tube 16mm in diameter in the middle of a non-reflective cylinder 50mm in diameter
- 10 litres per minute flow
- 18W of radiation across the entire length of the tube

How would you calculate the actual radiation dosage, in mJ/cm^2, received by the water?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tough due to the absorption coefficient of water, so I suspect the power density will be less the farther away from the centerline you look.   But start by calculating the power density (watts per square cm) at the inner diameter. The energy that a square-cm of the 'surface' of the water sees is then that power density multiplied by the total time that bit of water is in the tube. If, e.g. it takes 10 seconds to travel the entire tube, then the total energy hitting that square cm is Power * 10 = joules.

Again, that power density drops off as the square of distance from the centerline just due to spreading, and there's the additional loss due to absorption.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here:

https://www.cefas.co.uk/media/im3dgqpe/uv-disinfection-in-depuration-theory-and-practice-dj-passed.pdf

It suggests a path length of 2.5cm, the meaning of 'path length' I believe is the path of the light, but I'm not exactly sure how this was derived.

Irradiance is then given by:

(total uv flux in watts) / (2 * pi^2 * emitting length of tube * path length) * (2α + sin(2α)), where α is the angle between the mid point of the emitting length to the path length and the end of the emitting length:

[image]

So although we can measure the tube emitting length, it seems that it is typically 5cm less, so therefore 84.5cm in my example hence:

tan α = 42.25cm/2.5cm, hence α = 1.51169 radians

therefore, irradiance, E = 13.6 mW/cm^2

This assumes the absorption coefficient is zero. The absorption coefficient for drinking water can be as high as 0.2 cm^-1, and for sea water higher still.

The correct value for irradiance is given by multiplying the value in air by e^(-1 * absorption coefficient * path length), hence 8.2 mW/cm^2

It is then necessary to know the volume of water in the system, and the flow rate.

For the example above it appears that the volume of water for a 90cm tube is typically  1.379l. If the flow rate is 10 litres per minute, then this is 0.16667 l/second. The 1.379l/0.16667 gives an exposure time of 8.274s. 8.274s * 8.2 mW/cm^2 = 68.0 mJ/cm^2

This means that for example where I found a purifier quoting 12 GPM flow rate with a 55W tube, that this may be optimistic, and it could be less than half of that if you require 99.99% reduction with poor water conditions.)

(note the above does not consider reflections from the walls, which might help some - it does seem however that the system needs to be kept as a fairly narrow tube, and there is not too much advantage in using shorter tubes, especially given the impact of the tube length.)